# Cryptarithmetic puzzle

Tags: c++, puzzle, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

I am trying to solve this cryptarithmetic puzzle TWO + TWO = FOUR and I used a raw brute force, but I can't figure out where I am making mistake. The idea here is that it tries all possible combinations of numbers from 0 to 10 and all numbers that are assigned to characters must be distinct. By definition

> a cryptarithmetic puzzle is a mathematical game where the digits of
>   some numbers are represented by letters (or symbols). Each letter
>   represents a unique digit. The goal is to find the digits such that a
>   given mathematical equation is verified:
>   In this case:

```
   TWO
 + TWO
 ------ 
= FOUR
```

This code goes through all possible combinations until it finds the solution that satisfies the problem. Constraint for it is given in `else if` statement.
First `if` statement simply checks if numbers are same, and if they are, it just skips that iteration.

My desired output is to see **all** correct solutions displayed.

```
int T, W, O, F, U, R;

for (T = 0; T < 10; T++)
{
    for (W = 0; W < 10; W++)
    {
        for (O = 0; O < 10; O++)
        {
            for (F = 0; F < 10; F++)
            {
                for (U = 0; U < 10; U++)
                {
                    for (R = 0; R < 10; R++)
                    {
                        if ((T == W) || (T == O) || (T == F) || (T == U) || (T == R) || (W == O) || (W == F) || (W == U) || (W == R) || (O == F) || (O == U) || (O == R) || (F == U) || (F == R) || (U == R))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else if (200 * T + 20 * W + 2 * O == F * 1000 + O * 100 + U * 10 + R * 0) {
                            cout << "T = " << T << endl
                                << "W = " << W << endl
                                << "O = " << O << endl
                                << "F = " << F << endl
                                << "U = " << U << endl
                                << "R = " << R << endl << endl;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get bunch of results and interestingly enough, only the last result is fine, where it gives:

```
T = 7
W = 6
O = 5
F = 1
U = 3
R = 0
```

Comment: There's no harm in explaining the code and what it does, it's kind of hard due to all the loops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`R * 0` should be `R * 1` .

The answer you got that happened to be correct was the one where `R = 0`  (because when `R` is `0`, `R * 0` is the same as `R * 1`). I guess you also want to start `F` from `1` as typically cryptarithms don't allow leading zeros.